# Why is X(0) the DC component

Tags: dft

Why exactly is  X(0) the DC component of a signal?

How is it equal to N times x(n)'s average value and why it is at X(0)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follows from the DFT definition. It's defined as

\begin{equation}
X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-j2\pi \frac{kn}{N}}
\end{equation}

So $X(0)$ is

\begin{equation}
X(0) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-j2\pi \frac{0 \cdot n}{N}}
\end{equation}

Having $k=0$ gives $e^0=1$ all the time so that

\begin{equation}
X(0) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) 1
\end{equation}

Comparing this to the average

\begin{equation}
\overline{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n)
\end{equation}

shows that $X(0) = N \overline{x}$

Comment: So when removing the DC component, what is X(0) applied to?

Comment: If the signal is mean-free, X(0) will just be zero. Similarly, to make a signal mean-free, just set X(0)=0

Comment: @jan Just setting $X(0) = 0$ removes the signal mean-free in its frequency-domain representation, but to do the same in the time domain, we need to translate this to the time domain via the iDFT, or equivalently, subtract $\bar{x}$ from each of the time domain quantities $x[n], 0 \leq n \leq N-1$.